# Document link on front end in Wagtail

Tags: django, wagtail

If I upload a document to the Wagtail CMS, how can I make it available on the front end for download? Is there a specific template tag?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Once you have a reference to the document object, its `.url` property will give you the correct URL for downloads:

```
<a href="{{ document.url }}">{{ document.title }}</a>
```

As for how you get that reference in the first place - usually you'd do it by associating it with a foreign key to `wagtaildocs.Document`, in much the same way that the tutorial shows [associating images with pages](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.0.1/getting_started/tutorial.html#images):

```
from wagtail.documents.edit_handlers import DocumentChooserPanel

class MyPage(Page):
    # ...
    related_document = models.ForeignKey(
        'wagtaildocs.Document', blank=True, null=True,
         on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name='+'
    )

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        # ...
        DocumentChooserPanel('related_document')
    ]
```

(in this case, you would then refer to the document within the template as `page.related_document`, e.g. `<a href="{{ page.related_document.url }}">`.)

Comment: Thank you so much! And if I wanted to utilize it in the Streamfield, I assume a DocumentChooserBlock would suffice, similar to how images are handled?

Comment: @LazerFriends Yes. The default rendering of a DocumentChooserBlock will be a link to the document; you can customise the rendering as shown at http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.0.1/topics/streamfield.html#template-rendering (and in this case, the block's value is the document object).